# Imagick knowing the image size? (file size)

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

```
 $im = new Imagick($path);
 $im->resizeImage();

 echo $im->calc_image_size(); ? //> 121312 Bytes
```

Is there a calc_image_size or I have to write in a file and check the dimension? (fail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getImageSize throws a Deprecated.

```
Imagick::getImageSize is deprecated. Imagick::getImageLength should be used instead
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagelength.php

Comment: Imagick::getImageLength doesn't work with WEBP format

Answer (score 2):

If you compress the image you can determine the size like this

```
$data = $im->__toString();
$imageSize = strlen($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

See this [Imagick::getImageSize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagesize.php)

Comment: This function is deprecated and was deprecated when you answered. Use `getImageLength()` instead.